# SOA BPEL binary text to MTOM attachment

Tags: soap, soa, bpel, weblogic11g

I have an ftp adapter in BPEL composite to get an xml file with binary text data in it.

```
<urn:Content fileName="abc.png" mimeCode="image/png">
 iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABpAAAAPyCAIAAAD0RQtg
</urn:Content>
```

BPEL composite calls OSB service that supports MTOM attachment for content element.
How can i convert binary text to MTOM in BPEL and pass it as on attachment  before calling OSB service ?

like

```
  <urn:Content fileName="abc.png" mimeCode="image/png"><inc:Include    href="cid:123444" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></urn:Content>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you doing something not covered by the tutorial here? https://blogs.oracle.com/sujit/entry/mtom_soap_with_attachment_in

Comment: Yes, had to create OSB service that does it by pass by reference.

Comment: So it seems you have solved this? Please add your own answer for future visitors. Thanks.